# Why is the linker not recognizing the entry point defined in my linker script

Tags: cmake, linker, arm, stm32, linker-scripts

I am trying to cross-compile with target as STM32F030F4P6,I set up my startup.c & startup.h files containing my vector table. I have written 2 linker scripts one for memory & other for sections. as per the datasheet the STM32f030F4 after a system reset sets the PC to 0x00000000,& vector table must be present at this address as after incrementing it must execute Reset_Handler(system reset) at 0x00000004 and the initialize the system.

When I link this the linker gives me the following warning

> `" warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 00008000"`

```
Question
Why is the linker not detecting my Entry point defined by ENTRY(Reset_Handler)?
```

Please find my source & Header files & the linker scripts.

script.ld
This contains the sections

> ```
> ENTRY(Reset_Handler)
>
>
> SECTIONS
> {
>   .text :
>   {
>     *(.isr_vector)
>     *(.text)
>     *(.rodata)
>     _etext= .;
>   }> FLASH 
>
>   .data :
>   {
>     _sdata = .;
>     *(.data)
>     _edata = .;
>   }> SRAM AT> FLASH
>
>   .bss :
>   {
>     _sbss = .;
>     *(.bss)
>     _ebss = .;
>   }> SRAM
>
> }
> ```

memory.ld
This file contains memory definitions.
Note-STM32F030F4P has only FLASH & RAM and so EXTMEMBx is defined as 0x00000000 of LENGTH 4K

> ```
> MEMORY
> {
>   FLASH     (rx)    :   ORIGIN = 0x08000000,   LENGTH = 16K
>   RAM       (xrw)   :   ORIGIN = 0x20000000,  LENGTH = 4K
>   EXTMEMB0  (rx)    :   ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0K
>   EXTMEMB1  (rx)    :   ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0K
>   EXTMEMB2  (rx)    :   ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0K
>   EXTMEMB3  (rx)    :   ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0K
> }
> ```

Startup.h
containing the vector definitions

> ```
> #include "stdint.h"
>
> /* Calculate the vlaue of stack. */ 
> /* Full- descending stack in cortex-m0 means stack must be placed at the end of SRAM. */
> /* Stack pointer is decremented as a a PUSH operation is executed */
>
> #define SRAM_Start  0x20000000U
> #define SRAM_End    SRAM_Start+4096U
> #define Stack_Start SRAM_End
>
>
> /* Vector Definitions */
> void Reset_Handler(void);
> void NMI_Handler(void)          __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
> void HardFault_Handler(void)    __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
> void SVCall_Handler(void)       __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
> void PendSV_Handler(void)       __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
> void SysTick_Handler(void)      __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
>
> void IRQ0_Handler(void)         __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
> void IRQ1_Handler(void)         __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
> void IRQ2_Handler(void)         __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
> void IRQ3_Handler(void)         __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
> void IRQ4_Handler(void)         __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
> void IRQ5_Handler(void)         __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
> void IRQ6_Handler(void)         __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
> void IRQ7_Handler(void)         __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
> void IRQ8_Handler(void)         __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
> void IRQ9_Handler(void)         __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
> void IRQ10_Handler(void)         __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
> void IRQ11_Handler(void)         __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
> void IRQ12_Handler(void)         __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
> void IRQ13_Handler(void)         __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
> void IRQ14_Handler(void)         __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
> void IRQ15_Handler(void)         __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
> void IRQ16_Handler(void)         __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
> void IRQ17_Handler(void)         __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
> void IRQ18_Handler(void)         __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
> void IRQ19_Handler(void)         __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
> void IRQ20_Handler(void)         __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
> void IRQ21_Handler(void)         __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
> void IRQ22_Handler(void)         __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
> void IRQ23_Handler(void)         __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
> void IRQ24_Handler(void)         __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
> void IRQ25_Handler(void)         __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
> void IRQ26_Handler(void)         __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
> void IRQ27_Handler(void)         __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
> void IRQ28_Handler(void)         __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
> void IRQ29_Handler(void)         __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
> void IRQ30_Handler(void)         __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
> void IRQ31_Handler(void)         __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
> ```

& finally
startup.c

> ```
> //Set initial SP value
> // PC increments to reset handler
> // branch to main
>
> #include "startup.h"
>
>
>
> // __attribute__((weak, alias("")))
>
> /* Vector Table */
> /* Subsequent to a system RESET PC is set to 0x00000000 */
> /* Vector Table must be present at 0x00000000 use __atribute__((section("section_name"))) to place vector table at "section_name" */
> /* Use arm-none-eabi-objdump -h/-S to verify if "section_name" is generated for vector table */
> /* Value of SP is the first item in the vector table & henceforth msp is loaded */
> /* Second value of vector table is RESET HANDLER, */
> /* Core Systems must be initialized here such as CLOCK, etc.*/
> /* it is from RESET HANDLER the program flow is branched to user application */
>
> uint32_t vector[] __attribute__((section(".isr_vector"))) = {
>     Stack_Start,
>     (uint32_t)&Reset_Handler,
>     (uint32_t)&NMI_Handler,
>     (uint32_t)&HardFault_Handler,
>     (uint32_t)0x00000000,
>     (uint32_t)0x00000000,
>     (uint32_t)0x00000000,
>     (uint32_t)0x00000000,
>     (uint32_t)0x00000000,
>     (uint32_t)0x00000000,
>     (uint32_t)0x00000000,
>     (uint32_t)&SVCall_Handler,
>     (uint32_t)0x00000000,
>     (uint32_t)0x00000000,
>     (uint32_t)&PendSV_Handler,
>     (uint32_t)&SysTick_Handler,
>     (uint32_t)&IRQ0_Handler,
>     (uint32_t)&IRQ1_Handler,
>     (uint32_t)&IRQ2_Handler,
>     (uint32_t)&IRQ3_Handler,
>     (uint32_t)&IRQ4_Handler,
>     (uint32_t)&IRQ5_Handler,
>     (uint32_t)&IRQ6_Handler,
>     (uint32_t)&IRQ7_Handler,
>     (uint32_t)&IRQ8_Handler,
>     (uint32_t)&IRQ9_Handler,
>     (uint32_t)&IRQ10_Handler,
>     (uint32_t)&IRQ11_Handler,
>     (uint32_t)&IRQ12_Handler,
>     (uint32_t)&IRQ13_Handler,
>     (uint32_t)&IRQ14_Handler,
>     (uint32_t)&IRQ15_Handler,
>     (uint32_t)&IRQ16_Handler,
>     (uint32_t)&IRQ17_Handler,
>     (uint32_t)&IRQ18_Handler,
>     (uint32_t)&IRQ19_Handler,
>     (uint32_t)&IRQ20_Handler,
>     (uint32_t)&IRQ21_Handler,
>     (uint32_t)&IRQ22_Handler,
>     (uint32_t)&IRQ23_Handler,
>     (uint32_t)&IRQ24_Handler,
>     (uint32_t)&IRQ25_Handler,
>     (uint32_t)&IRQ26_Handler,
>     (uint32_t)&IRQ27_Handler,
>     (uint32_t)&IRQ28_Handler,
>     (uint32_t)&IRQ29_Handler,
>     (uint32_t)&IRQ30_Handler,
>     (uint32_t)&IRQ31_Handler,
> };
>
> /*Function defenition of reset handler*/
> /* it is from RESET HANDLER the program flow is branched to user application */
>
> void Reset_Handler(void)
> {
>     //  copy .data section
>     //  init .bss/SRAM to 0
>     //  init clocks etc..
>     //  call the application procedure
> }
>
> void Default_Handler(void)
> {
>     for(;;)
>     {
>         
>     }
>     //  Just loop as completion of this procedure will give other faults
> }
> ```

my toolchain file
arm-none-eabi.camke

> ```
> MESSAGE("Running : arm-none-eabi.cmake")
>
>     SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR  arm)
>     SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME       Generic)
>
>     SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS  TRUE)
>     SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WORKS  TRUE)
>
>     SET(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGTE_TYPE   STATIC_LIBRARY)
>
>     SET(TARGET      STM32F030x4)
>     SET(ARCH        armv6-m)
>     SET(CPU         cortex-m0)
>     SET(ARM_ISA     mthumb)
>
>     SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER    arm-none-eabi-gcc)
>     SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER  arm-none-eabi-g++)
>     SET(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER  arm-none-eabi-g++)
>     SET(CMAKE_SIZE          arm-none-eabi-size)
>     SET(CMAKE_OBJDUMP       arm-none-eabi-objdump)
>     SET(CMAKE_OBJCOPY       arm-none-eabi-objcopy)
>
>     SET(OPTIMISATION Og)
>     SET(DEBUG "ggdb")
>
>     SET(CMAKE_COMMON_FLAGS  "-march=${ARCH} -mcpu=${CPU} -${ARM_ISA} -D${TARGET} -${OPTIMISATION} -${DEBUG} -Wall -Wextra -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -ffreestanding -fno-builtin -nostdlib")
>     SET(CMAKE_ASM_FLAGS     "${CMAKE_COMMON_FLAGS}")
>     SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS       "${CMAKE_COMMON_FLAGS} ")
>     SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS     "${CMAKE_COMMON_FLAGS} -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -Wno-volatile -std=c++1z")
>     SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_COMMON_FLAGS} -nostartfiles -Wl,-Map,\"${TARGET}.map\" -nostartfiles -nolibc --specs=nosys.specs")
>
>     message("CMAKE_C_FLAGS = "          ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS})
>     message("CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS = "        ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS})
>     message("CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS = " ${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS})
> ```

CMakeLists.txt

> ```
> CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.20)
>
> INCLUDE("CMake/arm-none-eabi.cmake")
>
> SET(CMAKE_C_STANDARD    11)
> SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD  17)
>
>
> PROJECT(BLINKY VERSION 1.0.1 DESCRIPTION "Blinky Example")
> MESSAGE("Building " ${PROJECT_NAME})
>
> FILE(GLOB_RECURSE
>     LDSCRIPTS
>     "ldscripts/*.ld"
> )
>
> FOREACH(file ${LDSCRIPTS})
>     SET(CMAKE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CAMKE_LINKER_FLAGS} -T \"${file}\" ")
>     MESSAGE("Linker is Running " ${CMAKE_LINKER_FLAGS})
> ENDFOREACH()
>
>
>
> #Setup project headers
> INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
>     "Core/"
>     "Drivers/"
> )
>
> #Setup porject sources
> FILE(GLOB_RECURSE
>     APPLICATION_SOURCE
>     "Application/*.c"
>     "Application/*.cpp"
>     "Application/*.s"
>     "Core/*.c"
>     "Core/*cpp"
>     "Core/*.s"
>     "Drivers/*.c"
>     "Drivers/*.cpp"
>     "Drivers/*.s"
> )
>
>
> MESSAGE("CMake build directory" ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
>
> ADD_EXECUTABLE(${TARGET}.elf ${APPLICATION_SOURCE})
>
> #ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(${TARGET}.bin ALL DEPENDS ${TARGET}.elf COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} -O binary ${TARGET}.elf ${TARGET}.bin)
> #ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(${TARGET}.hex ALL DEPENDS ${TARGET}.elf COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} -O ihex ${TARGET}.elf ${TARGET}.hex)
>
> ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(OUTPUT ${TARGET}.bin DEPENDS ${TARGET}.elf COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} -O binary ${TARGET}.elf ${TARGET}.bin)
> ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(OUTPUT ${TARGET}.hex DEPENDS ${TARGET}.elf COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} -O ihex ${TARGET}.elf ${TARGET}.hex)
> ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(${TARGET}_bin DEPENDS ${TARGET}.bin)
> ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(${TARGET}_hex DEPENDS ${TARGET}.hex)
>
> ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(SIZE ALL ${CMAKE_SIZE} ${TARGET}.elf DEPENDS ${TARGET}.elf)
> ```

I understand this is definitely not the best way to write startup files. but the point is to make it run & improve to write startup file.

Comment: Can you also provide your Makefile? It looks like you are missing the flags `--specs=nosys.specs  --specs=nano.specs`

Comment: provided the toolchain file containing all the flags, I tried building with following flags -nostartfiles -nolibc --specs=nosys.specs --specs=nano.specs -nostdlib, it still does not work.

Comment: please provide a minimal example that demonstrates the problem (command lines preferred to makefile)

Comment: Already shared the toolcahin faile bute here are the flags from the ninja build file. c 
        FLAGS = -march=armv6-m -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -DSTM32F030x4 -Og -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -ffreestanding -fno-builtin -nostdlib -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -Wno-volatile -std=c++1z -g
  LINK_FLAGS = -march=armv6-m -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -DSTM32F030x4 -Og -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -ffreestanding -fno-builtin -nostdlib -nostartfiles -Wl,-Map,"STM32F030x4.map" -nostartfiles -nolibc --specs=nosys.specs --specs=nano.specs -nostdlib

Comment: Ask the linker for a map file. Is `Reset_Handler` listed? Is `_Reset_Handler` (with a leading underscore) listed?

Answer (score 0):

_start is part of Newlib C library. Did you provide it on linker command line ?

Comment: I have shared my linker flags, please help me out. how can i not give these flags